# HoloEverywhere+ Sherlock error

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I've installed HoloEverywhere and Action Bar Sherlock, and I've added ABS as library to holoeverywhere. But Holoeverywhere have a bullet on it, and when installing as library for my project, it's a red X on it.
[image: error 1]

Comment: Please be more specific or provide a screenshot

Comment: Please can you explain more detailed?

Comment: I've imported HOLO and ABS, after it i've imported holo to abs(that's ok), and I've imported abs to holo (the same error as on screen)

Comment: Import ABS project to Eclipse! Mark it as a library and then go to Holoeverywhere properties and add ABS as a library !

Comment: The same error(the screen is actual)